# Multiple mappers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run 2 independent mappers on the same input file in a hadoop program using one job. I want the output of both the mappers to go into a single reducer. I face an issue with running multiple mappers. I was using MultipleInputs class. It was working fine by running both the mappers but yesterday i noticed that it is running only one map function that is the second MultipleInputs statement seems to overwrite the first one. I dont find any change done to the code to show this different behavior suddenly :( Please help me in this.. The main function is :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = new Job(conf, "mapper accepting whole file at once");          
            job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            job.setJarByClass(TestMultipleInputs.class);
            job.setMapperClass(Map2.class);    
            job.setMapperClass(Map1.class);  
            job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);  
            job.setInputFormatClass(NLinesInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
**  MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("Rec"), NLinesInputFormat.class, Map1.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("Rec"), NLinesInputFormat.class, Map2.class);**    
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path("testMulinput"));
              job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Whichever Map class is used in the last MultipleInputs statement gets executed. Like in here the Map2.class gets executed.

Comment: what is your "Rec"? And are you using the same file for both mappers?

Comment: Yes.. I am using the same input file "Rec" for both mappers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mappers can't read the same file at the same time.

Solution (Workaround):
Create a duplicate of the input file (in this case let duplicate rec file be rec1). Then feed mapper1 with rec and mapper2 with rec1.

Both mappers are executed parallel so you don't need to worry about reducer output because both mappers output will be shuffled so that equal keys from both the files go to same reducer.

so output is what you want.

Hope this helps to others who are facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to read from the same file at the same time with two separate `Mapper`s (at least not without some devilishly hack-ish trickery which you should probably avoid).

In any case, you cant have two `Mapper` classes set for the same job - the latter call to `setMapperClass(class)` will always overwrite the former. If you need two `Mapper`s to run simultaneously, you'll need to make two separate jobs, and ensure that there are enough mappers available on your cluster to run them both simultaneously (if there aren't any available after the first job starts the second job will have to wait for it to finish, running sequentially rather than simultaneously.)

However, due to the lack of a guarantee that the `Mapper`s will run concurrently, ensure that the functionality of your MapReduce jobs is not reliant on their concurrent execution.

Comment: So do you mean that I cannot create multiple mappers on the same input file? Also if I make two separate jobs, can I have one reducer which accepts the output of both the mappers?

Comment: You cannot have the mappers reading the input file at the same time, but you can use the same file as input to two non-concurrent jobs. If you use two separate jobs, *and it is appropriate*, you can have one reducer class which can handle both mappers' output. Bear in mind this reducer class will be instantiated separately, it wont be the exact same reducer instance, merely instantiated from the same class.

Comment: Sorry I think I get confused a bit..:( As per my understanding, MultipleInputs class is used when you have to run multiple mappers. I adopted it here since I do not want the mappers to be run at same time since my mappers are independent, only that it uses the same input.. But what I find is the MultipleInputs statement coming last overwrites the previous one. The setMapperClass(class) even if not written, doesnot seem to play a role here.the MultipleInputs statement needs to run its statement everytime it is written and then it should run both the map classes here, right?

Comment: I can't say I'm too familiar with `MultipleInputs` but I imagine the issue is likely stemming from the fact that you're trying to use the same file as input to both mappers. `MultipleInputs` to me implies that the files will be distinctly separate, thus being multiple files as opposed to a single file. Try duplicating your input file and setting "Rec" as input to one file and "Rec2" as input to the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs:) It worked now by duplicating... :)

Comment: Have a think about whether you *need* the two mappers to be part of the same job, it might be better to have the 2 separate jobs using the same input file, different mappers and same reducer class. That way you can avoid the duplication of your input files - and considering hadoop is usually for large amounts of data, you'll likely want to avoid data duplication.

Comment: Yes yes.. I am thinking on that too, I just wanted to try out as a part of learning, earlier I was not aware if two different jobs will output to the same reduce function. I will now work on that and modify my code. Thanks again:)

Comment: Hey did you find anything on using two jobs on same input and providing to the reduce function. Coz I'm kind of stuck on that one. Any help is Appreciated.Here's My question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860959/multiple-inputs-adding-same-input-to-multiple-mappers-for-comparison