# hadoop map concurrent reading

Tags: hadoop, io

The following stackoverflow post make the statement that it's not possible to have two mappers  within a same job, reading the same data concurrently.
[Multiple mappers in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207799/multiple-mappers-in-hadoop)

One of the workaround proposed is to duplicate the input data.

I would like to understand a little bit more this constraint, what makes concurrent reads impossible within the same job (not handled by choice or related to technical constraints) ?